# Proposal for Markdown buttons design

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown

Markdown panel that is used now in Stack Exchange sites has button images with medium resolution.

It would be good to have these buttons in good quality, because in Retina display images are blurred. For example, Microsoft uses SVG images in their sites for new browsers and PNG for old.

We draw new graphical representation in vector format at
http://highrobotics.com/we-did-it/appdesign/stackoverflow-markdown-buttons.aspx
and it is used in our PageDown modification.

Hope that it will be helpful.

Comment: +1 just for the effort. That's just awesome.

Comment: This is awesome. I want it.

Comment: That’s very kind of you!

Comment: Why even bother with old browsers?

Comment: @bjb568: Indeed, looks like [SVG CSS sprites](http://caniuse.com/svg-css) should work in all the [supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), so we could just switch to SVG icons and drop the PNG versions entirely.

Comment: @Ilmari Hooray! And thanks for the link.

Comment: How about the site logo, SE logo, and top-bar buttons?

Comment: We will be happy to create design for stack exchange sites. However there is a need to discuss what to do. Stackoverflow has own designer and there are a lot of work to do. Pagedown project is not tired to SE and can be used in any site. So our design can be applied now in Pagedown. And also can be used in SE as a basis.